# Configure the "Remote Desktop" RemoteApp in TSGateway / RDWeb

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, rdp, rds

We have an installation of TS/RDGateway with the RDWeb IIS installed.

The "Remote Desktop" tab is also configured, but it lacks an option for "/multimon" but DOES let users configure their performance/connection speed (e.g. 2MBps).

When they use the "Remote Desktop" RemoteApp, they have no such options but the /multimon flag is passed by default.

How can I edit the settings which ultimately get set in the .RDP files in C:\Windows\Web\RDWeb\rdp which ultimately gets sent as a remoteApp?